# How to display a product image on the checkout page for store

Tags: expresso-store

I would like to display an image from the products channel on the checkout page using STORE by Exp:resso.

If I use the normal channesl tag the image display's, but seems to show all products in the channel. If I use limit="1" it only shows the one image.

Many thanks

Graham

Answer (score 2):

You will want to have the channels entries loop inside of the cart tags. I am going to use the checkout tag but this would work with the cart and order tags too.

```
{exp:store:cart}
 {items}
  {exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}" limit="1"}
   {title}
   <img src="{images_custom_field_name_here}" />
  {/exp:channel:entries}
 {/items}
{/exp:store:cart}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your reply. I also found the answer in the STORE docs and give it a test. I used the code below, which worked fine.

```
{exp:channel:entries entry_id="{entry_id}"}
 <a href="{path='store/detail'}/{url_title}"><img src="{product_image_one}" alt="{title}" height="100" width="100"></a>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```